# Visual Basic / Visual Studio 2013 Trackbar Movement Direction

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, trackbar

I am writing a program that will hopefully simulate events based upon the direction of movement and the value of a trackbar.  Using the value of the trackbar is easy, but I can't figure out how to determine if the user is moving it in a positive or negative direction.  For example, if the user moves it from 0 to 10 I would like for a variable to equal something (1 or true preferably) and do the same if the user moved it in a negative direction.  Thanks for your help!

-Doug

Comment: Hmmm...perhaps you could declare a variable to hold the **previous** value of the Trackbar, then compare the new value to the previous value by subtracting the two and determining if the difference is positive or negative.  By sheer coincidence, you also want to do something whether the bar has been moved in a positive of negative direction.  For lack of a term for this magical process, I shall call this the "delta" value; and I hereby decree that the uppercase version of the fourth letter of the Greek alphabet shall be its written form.  So say we all.

Comment: any reason vba is tagged? will this be used in a MS office environment?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks idle.  Thank you for creating a definition for this before-unforeseen conundrum.  I tried declaring a variable to hold the previous value of the trackbar, but I couldn't quite figure out how to go about it since every time the trackbar is moved the variable is changed.

Edit:
Figured it out, sorry for being a noob...

Private Sub TrackBar1_Scroll(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TrackBar1.Scroll

```
    dir = TrackBar1.Value - tick

    If dir = 1 Then
        Label2.Text = "positive"
    ElseIf dir = -1 Then
        Label2.Text = "negative"
    End If
    tick = TrackBar1.Value
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: this should be comment?